# SQL - Version comparison

Tags: sql, comparison, version

this is my first question here.

I am building an SQL query in which I need to verify that the version of the object B is always lower or equal than the version of the object A. This is a link table, here is an example :

[image: Image path]

The query is :

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE B_VERSION <= A_VERSION
```

As you can see, it works for the 2 first rows, but not the third, because AA0 is detected as smaller than H08 while it shouldn't (when we arrive at Z99 the next version number is AA0 so the <= operator doesn't work anymore).

So I would like to do something like to parse the version to compare on how many letters are they in the versions,  and only if both versions have the same number of letters then I use the <= operator.

I don't know however how to do that in an SQL query. Didn't find anything usefull on google neither. Do you have a solution ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key for solving this problem is the function **PATINDEX**. You can find more information [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395(v=sql.105).aspx).

This query takes the value of A_VERSION and finds the first occurrence of a number. Then uses this position to divide the value in two parts. The first part is padded to the right with spaces because it is alphabetic, while the second part is padded to the right with zeros ('0') because it is numeric.

The same process occurs for B_VERSION.

Noticed that in this example, each part is assumed to be of maximum **5** characters, so this will work in your case for versions ranging from A0 to ZZZZZ99999. Feel free to adjust as you need.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE RIGHT(SPACE(5) 
            + SUBSTRING(A_VERSION, 
                        1, 
                        PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', A_VERSION) - 1), 5)
      + RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 5) 
              + SUBSTRING(A_VERSION, 
                          PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', A_VERSION), 
                          LEN(A_VERSION)), 5) 
    <= RIGHT(SPACE(5) 
             + SUBSTRING(B_VERSION, 
                         1, 
                         PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', B_VERSION) - 1), 5) 
      + RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 5) 
              + SUBSTRING(B_VERSION, 
                          PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', B_VERSION), 
                          LEN(B_VERSION)) ,5)
```

If you are going to do this operation in many places, you might consider creating a function for this operation.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks! It helped a lot however I am using sql developer and I cannot use PATINDEX with this software, I found the equivalent which is REGEXP_INSTR, it works very similarly.

I used this alrogithm that filters out the lines where there are more letters in VERSION_B than VERSION_A and then filter out the lines where VERSION_B is bigger than VERSION_A when they have both the same quantity of letters:

```
WHERE
  (REGEXP_INSTR(VERSION_B, '[0-9]') < REGEXP_INSTR(VERSION_A, '[0-9]')) OR
  (REGEXP_INSTR(VERSION_B, '[0-9]') = REGEXP_INSTR(VERSION_A, '[0-9]') AND VERSION_B <= VERSION_A)
```